# How to convert the charactes to regex?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

```
var spclChrs="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-_";

/*Accepted Characters*/
var id = $(this).attr('id');
var textVal = $("#" + id).val();
$("#" + id).css({ "background": "", "border": "" });
for (var i = 0; i < textVal.length; i++) {
    if (spclChrs.indexOf(textVal.charAt(i)) == -1) {
        if (sessionLang == 0) {
            $().toastmessage('showErrorToast', "Invalid  character(s) entered.");
        }
        if (sessionLang == 1) {
            $().toastmessage('showErrorToast', "Los caractere(s) entraron.");
        }
        $("#" + id).css({ "background": "#FFCECE", "border": "1px solid red", });
        textVal = textVal.slice(0, -1);
        $("#" + id).val(textVal);
        return false;
    }
}
```

I have the following validations for textbox on keyup and keydown events. I am accepting the characters that are specified in my variable "spclChars".Instead of manually specifying the characters, how I can do this through Ragex keeping my this code same.

Comment: You mean you want the code to generate `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-_"` ?

Comment: I think you want this: `var spclchars = [a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]`

Comment: Yes. But spclChars.indexOf() should work.

Comment: @Mr_Green Yes. Since I am using spclchars .indexOf() it is not working.

Comment: `var spclchars = Array.apply(0,Array(256)).reduce(function(s,_,i){ var v=String.fromCharCode(i); return /[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]/.test(v) ? s+v : s }, "")`

Answer (score 0):

I would say the following is what you are after:

```
// Regular expression to check against
// [^ creates a negative character class, saying that it only looks for characters NOT defined in this class
// \w = Any (english) alphanumerical characters (a-zA-Z0-9)
// -_
// ] end of class
// This [^\w-_] means any character that isn't a-zA-Z0-9-_.
// g = global flag
var reg = /[^\w-_]/g;   

var id = $(this).attr('id');
var textVal = $("#" + id).val();
$("#" + id).css({ "background": "", "border": "" });

// Test the string towards the regular expression
// true = fits the expression (Have used special characters)
// false = Doesn't fit (only used a-zA-Z0-9-_)
if (reg.test(textVal)) {
    if (sessionLang == 0) {
        $().toastmessage('showErrorToast', "Invalid  character(s) entered.");
    }

    if (sessionLang == 1) {
        $().toastmessage('showErrorToast', "Los caractere(s) entraron.");
    }
    $("#" + id).css({ "background": "#FFCECE", "border": "1px solid red", });
    textVal = textVal.slice(0, -1);
    $("#" + id).val(textVal);
    return false;
```

PS: There seems to be some code missing at the end from your example :)

Comment: I have to loop through to check and assign other condition as well.